# UnassignedReferenceException on an assigned variable (unity 3D)

Tags: c#, animation, scripting, unity-game-engine

i'm very new to Unity (using 4.5) and i'm trying to learn unity 3D. I have this small "game" where I just want to swing an axe to kill spiders. I have created my animation named "AxeSwing" and a small script to trigger the animation when I click my left button. The probleme is that I have an error saying that my variable "attackAnimationClip" has nothing assigned to it. As you can see on the screen shot it is assigned and when I left click the animation trigger and come back to my IdleAxe animation.

Here the script:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animation))]
public class AttackAnimation : MonoBehaviour {
    public AnimationClip attackAnimationClip;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            animation.Play(attackAnimationClip.name);
        else if (IsAttackFinished)
            animation.CrossFade(animation.clip.name);
     }

    private bool IsAttackFinished
    {
        get { return animation[attackAnimationClip.name].time > animation[attackAnimationClip.name].length;  }
    }
}
```

[image: Here's the error from the debugger, and it shows that my variable is assigned.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the animation attached to your GameObject you can do this:

```
 animation.Play("AxeSwing");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. There is no overload for `Play(AnimationClip)`

Comment: Try checking if attackAnimationClip is null.  Then try printing the `name`. Sometimes when playing the scene some dragged and dropped properties in the scene are lost (often with prefabs).

Comment: It Print "AxeSwing" every click